# Is it possible to automatically migrate users with FusionAuth?

Tags: single-sign-on, fusionauth

Some cloud SSO providers offer means of automatically (just in time) migrating users from an old application to the new Identity Provider.  If the user does not yet exist in the IdP database, the system can call custom code to try to authenticate the user against the source web app and if successful creates the user in the IdP.

I did notice that FusionAuth supports custom code to hash the password to authenticate against an imported password.  That seems great, but I would prefer incremental migration of users.

Comment: Hi @MarkE - are you referring to something like Auth0's database connection (https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db)?

Comment: Yes, perhaps something like the auth0 database connections.  However, a call to an external REST API to test authentication might be adequate also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is on our roadmap and we are looking at implementing it using a REST API for flexibility. If you'd like to discuss your requirements and make sure that our implementation of this feature will work for you, contact us using the Contact form on our website here:

https://fusionauth.io/contact

You can also provide additional details on the Github issue I created to track this feature. That is located here:

https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/232

I also added some information to that Github issue about how you can implement this in your backend currently. If you have comments or additional feedback, you can add it to the Github issue.

Comment: Sounds great!   Thanks for the responsiveness for this use case.